# In VSCode, Exit Vim Insert Mode on Save

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I use VSCode with the VSCodeVim extension. When in Insert Mode, I can press "CMD-S" to save. When I do, I would also like to exit Insert Mode automatically instead of pressing "ESC" as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17):

I was looking for a solution similar to this issue as well.

It appears that multiple commands cannot be mapped to key bindings in vscode; however, I've found an extension, [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros), that let's you do this.

If you use the below steps with the macros extension, I believe that you'll have the solution you're looking for, until vscode implements something to address this feature request.

Step one, edit user settings with the below:

```
"macros": {
    "saveAndExitVimInsertMode": [
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        "extension.vim_escape"
    ]
}
```

Step two, edit keyboard bindings:

```
    {
    "key": "cmd+s",
    "command": "macros.saveAndExitVimInsertMode"
    }
```

Comment: small typo in the name "saveand..." vs "saveAnd".
After fixing this, it works great

Comment: Note that you may need to save the settings files via some means other than cmd+s because cmd-s will fail if you enable to keyboard binding before successfuly enabling the macro.

Comment: This worked great...thanks a bunch! For future readers, to open your prerefernces and keyboard bindings: "...edit the underlying settings.json file by using the Open Settings (JSON) command" and the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" command as well.

Answer (score 8):

VSCodeVim extension supports insert mode key bindings. [Here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#viminsertmodekeybindingsvimothermodeskeybindings) is a link to the extension readme that describes this feature.

Here is a snippet you could put in your settings.json.

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": [ "<C-s>" ],
        "commands": [
            { "command": "workbench.action.files.save" },
            { "command": "extension.vim_escape" }
        ]
    }
],
```

After reloading your vscode window you can pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to exit insert mode and save the file.

Comment: Odd. I tested it using ctrl+n because I have something else bound to ctrl+s and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: I created an issue on the extension's github: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2411

Comment: Thanks, I've been binding it to `[":", "w"]` for the time being but takes an additional keystroke.

Answer (score -1):

open Show Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). enter 'open keyboard shortcut' ,
search 'extension.vim_escape' and edit it to be 2 times caps lock key.