# In VSCode Neovim, press Ctrl+S to save file and switch to normal mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, neovim

I use VSCode Neovim plugin, and I would like to use "Ctrl+S" key for "save this file, and then switch to normal mode", which visually change the cursor style from "thin" to "solid".

My vim/nvim config file is with:

```
"--- ctrl + s  saving
noremap  <silent> <C-S>  :update<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <C-S>  <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <silent> <C-S>  <C-O>:update<CR><ESC>
```

But in VSCode, edit some words, then press "Ctrl+S" just save the file, didn't switch to normal mode. i.e. the `<C-O>:update<CR><ESC>` is not executed. How can I let it be executed?

Tried solution:
[In VSCode, Exit Vim Insert Mode on Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050087/in-vscode-exit-vim-insert-mode-on-save)

`settings.json`:

```json
    "macros": {
        "saveAndExitVimInsertMode": [
            "workbench.action.files.save",
            "extension.neovim.escape"
        ]
    }
```

`keybindings.json`:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        //"command": "workbench.action.files.save"
        "command": "macros.saveAndExitVimInsertMode"
    },
```

But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by the following config in `setttings.json`:

```json
    "macros": {
        "saveAndExitVimInsertMode": [
            "workbench.action.files.save",
            //"extension.nvim_escape" // not working
            "vscode-neovim.escape" // working
        ]
    },
```

Reference: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/74#issuecomment-563214553

Answer (score 0):

Another nice solution is to use the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) Extension:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+s",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && neovim.init && neovim.mode == 'insert'",
  "args": {
    "sequence": ["workbench.action.files.save", "vscode-neovim.escape"]
  }
}
```

That way, you only send the escape signal if you are acutally in insert mode.